# Save workbook without macros

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I have to save a workbook, that has macros, without these.
The way appears to be simple as I have read in this forum either, but I stille have problems.
The code I have found here, that is said to work properly, is this:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Thisworkbook.Path & "\" & sfilename & ".xlsx", 51 
Application.Workbooks.Open (spath) 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Also this:

```
Activeworkbook.SaveAs filename:="aaaa.xlsx", fileformat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Createbackup:=false
```

Well, I manage to save the file with ".xlsx" extension with both the above codes and in the folder it is said to be an excel file (without mentioning macros as it is not an ".xlsm"), but as I open that new .xlsx file, it has macro running!

So, I have an .xlsx with macros.

Surely I miss something.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible for an xlsx file to have macros, so whatever macro is running is not in that workbook.

Comment: I totally agree with @Rory comment. Could be that you have another opened workbook with macros? Or maybe your personal macro workbook? Or an add-in?